# Javascript: Is a “static site, editable content” blogging system a realistic use for the GitHub API?

Tags: javascript, github, xmlhttprequest, blogs, github-api

I am working on a GitHub gist based blogging system that will allow a static site hosted on github pages to be editable on the go. That way you can edit/correct typos/post by creating and editing gists with gist.github.com interface rather than having to have development environment set up, regenerating the site, and pushing.

Because it needs to be static, I’m writing it in (plain) Javascript.

From what I understand the API only allows a limited number of requests without authentication.

Is there a way that I can:
- Use client-side javascript
- Let visitors view the blog an unlimited number of times
- Have the blog author authenticate, but not everyone viewing it

I only need to read from the API, not write; editing is done using GitHub’s interface.

This will be a plain JS app that GitHub users host on github pages, so I’m not sure how authentication could be done securely.

Is this a feasible thing to do?

Comment: "Let visitors view the blog an unlimited number of times" -- this is not possible. To keep the API fast for everyone, it has rate limiting in place: https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting.

Comment: Regarding "Have the blog author authenticate, but not everyone viewing it" -- one thing you might consider is using a scopeless OAuth token in your JS application: https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes. Such a token could be used to make API calls and identify the owner of the token, but it wouldn't grant any permissions other that reading publicly available data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. It think no scope is what I was looking for. 5000 requests per hour would work for my purposes, but it’s a question whether it’s worth building a whole app around the API if people will have to migrate when their blogs gets really popular. Of course, I could also contact GitHub...